# How to add image to Togglebutton without using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I'm trying to add a image to a togglebutton in WPF - C#. The thing is that the assignment I'm working on can't be made with the use of XAML at all. I've tried to set the Content property to an image, but all I get is a normal togglebutton, which isn't helping my cause at all.

```
    myToggleButton = new ToggleButton();
    myImage = new Image();
    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
    bmi.BeginInit();
    bmi.UriSource = new Uri("myImageResource.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
    bmi.EndInit();
    myImage.Source = bmi;
    myToggleButton.Content = myImage;
```

Hope I supplied enough info, if not please ask for more.

Updated @Phil Wright:

When I ad an image like this:

```
    myImage = new Image();
    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
    bmi.BeginInit();
    bmi.UriSource = new Uri("myImageResource.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
    bmi.EndInit();
    myImage.Source = bmi;
```

it works...

Update @Matt West:

```
    myGrid.Children.add(MyToggleButton); // This gives me an empty ToggleButton
    myGrid.Children.add(MyImage); // This gives me an image with content
```

Comment: Cosidering the last two lines you are clearly in bug-land. You should try doing this in a clean project and see if you can even reproduce this under controlled conditions.

Comment: Try what? and reproduce what?

Comment: Your bloody problem of course...

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but you need to be more specific. What do you propose I do? This code is taken from a fresh clean project, where the only files in the project are the .cs file and 4 bitmaps.

Comment: You could have said that you actually did what i proposed in your earlier comment, i assumed that you tried to do this in a convoluted environment. But this is weird, since i cannot reproduce this at all, it works as expected for me and as i noted those last two lines make no sense at all.

Comment: Could you post the code that you get to run? that might be able to enlighten my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new toggle button but you aren't adding it to anything. The image is getting added to the toggle button but the actual toggle button isn't added as a Child to anything. You either need to add the toggle button in code behind with something like this:

```
this.AddChild(myToggleButton);
```

Or if you already have the toggle button defined in XAML with a name of myToggleButton then remove this line from your code above

```
myToggleButton = new ToggleButton();
```

Comment: Does it help if you specify a width and a height for the toggle button?

Comment: Not really. Defining width and height only alters the buttons size. Nothing happens if I define the width and height for the image

Answer (score 1):

As requested here is the code that works for me in its entirety:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="_Root">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var tb = new ToggleButton();
            var image = new Image();
            BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
            bmi.BeginInit();
            bmi.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/6.png", UriKind.Relative);
            bmi.EndInit();
            image.Source = bmi;
            tb.Content = image;
            _Root.Children.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

Where the image is a resource; as noted before those last two lines make no sense, if you can get the image to display on its own it should also display inside the button.

Comment: See this is wierd! Cause I just copy pasted your code into my projct and it still doesn't work. Guess I have some probs with setting in my VS. Thanks for Trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the provided bitmap resource is able to be located. If not then the image will be empty and so occupy no space and hence the toggle button looks empty.

Answer (score 0):

image of a toggle button can be set like this:

```
ToggleButton tgb = new ToggleButton();
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.BeginInit();
bmi.UriSource = new Uri("myImageResource.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
bmi.EndInit();
tgb.Content = new Image { Source = bmi };
```